# Can not receive message with Masstransit in .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, messaging, masstransit

I am working with Masstransit, RabbitMq and .NET core. I have problem when I want to publish message and receive. My `UserEventHandler` and `UserCommandHandler` class never calls. Can anybody help me? Bus is started. I also have a situation when I remove `UserEventHandler` class from registration my breakpoint stops on `UserCommandHandler` class.

Here is my `UserEventHandler` class:

```
public class UserEventHandler : IConsumer<IUserEvent>
{
    private ConcertDbContext _context;
    public UserEventHandler(ConcertDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUserEvent> context)
    {
        var concerts = _context.Concerts.Where(c => c.Name == context.Message.Name);
        foreach (var concert in concerts)
        {
            concert.SoldTickets = context.Message.TicketBuyed;
            _context.Concerts.Update(concert);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is my UserCommandHandler class:

```
public class UserCommandHandler : IConsumer<IUserCommand>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUserCommand> context)
    {
        await context.Publish<IUserEvent>(new UserEvent(context.Message.Name, context.Message.TicketBuyed));
    }
}
```

I registered UserCommandHandler here in Startup.cs class:

```
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<ConcertEventHandler>();
            x.AddConsumer<UserCommandHandler>();
            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(RabbitMqConstants.RabbitMqUri),
                    hst =>
                    {
                        hst.Username(RabbitMqConstants.Username);
                        hst.Password(RabbitMqConstants.Password);
                    });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.CreateConcertService, e =>
                {
                    e.PrefetchCount = 16;

                    e.ConfigureConsumer<ConcertEventHandler>(provider);
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.BuyCncertTicketService, e =>
                {
                    e.PrefetchCount = 16;

                    e.ConfigureConsumer<UserCommandHandler>(provider);
                });

                // or, configure the endpoints by convention
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
            }));
```

Here is I registered UserEventHandler class

```
                services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<ConcertCommandHandler>();
            x.AddConsumer<UserEventHandler >();
            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(RabbitMqConstants.RabbitMqUri),
                    hst =>
                    {
                        hst.Username(RabbitMqConstants.Username);
                        hst.Password(RabbitMqConstants.Password);
                    });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.CreateConcertService, e =>
                {
                    e.PrefetchCount = 16;

                    e.ConfigureConsumer<ConcertCommandHandler>(provider);
                });
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, RabbitMqConstants.BuyCncertTicketService, e =>
                {
                    e.PrefetchCount = 16;

                    e.ConfigureConsumer<UserEventHandler>(provider);
                });

                // or, configure the endpoints by convention
                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
            }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each service should be using separate queues, currently you are configuring each service with separate consumers on the same receive endpoint queue names. That will cause the messages to be moved to the *_skipped* queue since there is not a consumer on that service instance for the published message.

Also, remove the `cfg.ConfigureEndpoints` at the end of each service configuration. You are manually configuring your receive endpoints, so it will create duplicate queues and endpoints for your consumers.

Comment: How to do that? How to separate queues?

Comment: Well, don't use `RabbitMqConstants.CreateConcertService` on two separate endpoints with different consumers.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me